Scammed by a host or booking.com failure (CANT_CANCEL_hotel_overbooked)?
I booked an apartment in the Philippines through booking.com for the last week of April. The payment method is "pay at the property" and I gave my debit card number as a guarantee to make the reservation. The booking allows cancellation up to 24 hours before check-in. The host sent me a message to contact him to a personal email address to "proceed with the booking and make the payment".
As this sounded shady, I tried to cancel the booking. My surprise was that when I tried to cancel it, I got this error message.

Something went wrong


CANT_CANCEL_hotel_overbooked


Contact customer service

I contacted customer service and they told me that that the accommodation I had booked had been closed as they didn't make business with them anymore.
That the reservation was closed is not true. The reservation is confirmed and still up in their page. That means that when the free cancellation is over and I don't show up (and I can't show up because the host is unreachable), I will be charged on my debit card.

Who is responsible in this case of being charged and scammed, booking.com or the host? The problem arises when booking.com doesn't allow me to cancel the reservation through their webpage. On the other hand booking.com it's an intermediary between the property and the guest, so they can't cancel any booking. Only the property can cancel the booking. The property is unreachable.

Can I block booking.com on my debit card?
As I see it, there's a binding contract between me and the property through booking.com. So I would be breaking the contract.


They offered me reallocation, but I'm not interested.

Can I get reimbursed from booking,com once my debit card is charged for not showing up under these circumstances, instead of being reallocated?

What would you do in this situation?

What did you choose? Pay through Booking or pay at the property?

Pay at the property.

I’d call your card provider to report a possible fraud.

I would definitely recommend contacting your bank and explain the potential scam. They might be able to put a temporary hold on your card or offer other options.
